# Change data from one logical drive to another

Tags: windows, raid

I have a Fujitsu rx200S8 that has 2x500GB drives in a raid 0 configuration. I added 2x1TB new disks and created another raid 0.

How can I migrate the data from the old disks to the new ones without losing anything? The OS is 2012, and I have 10 VM on Hyper-V on it. My objective is to remove the old disks, i need them for another server.

Comment: Shutdown all VMs. Then copy the content with `robocopy /MT 16 /R:1 /W:1 /MIR /SEC /B <source> <dest> /XD "System Volume Information" $Recycle.Bin /XF *.tmp`.

Comment: Would that copy the boot sector too? I need a complete mirror of the disk so i can boot from it.

Comment: No, that would just copy all the files. The BCD can be (re-)created with `bcdboot %windir% /s <newdrive>:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can allow a long(ish) downtime:

- This would a very good opportunity to test your backup strategy. Honestly, just try this - can you get your system back to working state from your backup without the old disks present? This is doubly important with a RAID0 with its high inherent failure probability. BTW: Are you aware what you are getting into with a RAID0?
- Use something like Clonezilla to migrate the data to the new disks. I mention Clonezilla because it is free.

With minimal downtime, you would need to investigate 3rd party commercial cloning tools that can do this in a live system. When I last did something like this years ago, Acronis used to offer good tools for this, but other vendors might exist.

Comment: This is a server used for testing only, all data is not essential for day to day activity. Also the downtime is not a problem. I was thinking i need to make a system image but i was hoping my RAID controller could do the migration(i double checked but i asked here to be sure). I guess Clonezilla is easiest way.